# HighCharts - Add dynamic new functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I need to add new function

```
function(chart) { // on complete

chart.renderer.path(['M', 300, 0, 'L', 300, 300])
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    .add();

 chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 150, 'L', 500, 150])
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red'
    })
    .add();

 }
```

OR

```
function(chart) { // on complete
    var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth  * 0.5);
    var textY = chart.plotTop  + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5);

    var span = '<span id="pieChartInfoText" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">';
    span += '<span style="font-size: 32px">Upper</span><br>';
    span += '<span style="font-size: 16px">Lower</span>';
    span += '</span>';

    $("#addText").append(span);
    span = $('#pieChartInfoText');
    span.css('left', textX + (span.width() * -0.5));
    span.css('top', textY + (span.height() * -0.5));
}
```

to my existing chart. These functions are dynamic. They change each time i update database. How can i do that?.

I need a code to append this function to existing high charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your response.
I got the answer.

```
//Eg code : 

var customFunc = function( chart , code ) { 
 return new Function("chart" , code )( chart ); 
} 

// load chart new Function to chart 
function getChartFunction( chartObj ) { 

 if( newFunctionCode ){ 

   customFunc( chartObj , newFunctionCode ); 
  } 
 } 

 // new newFunctionCode eg: 
 chart.renderer.path(['M', 300, 0, 'L', 300, 300]) .attr({ 'stroke-width': 2, stroke: 'red' }).add(); 
 chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 150, 'L', 500, 150]) .attr({ 'stroke-width': 2, stroke: 'red' }).add();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put script in separate file and then use `getScript` to laod it whenever you want.

```
$.getScript("jscodefilr.js", function(){
alert("Running jscodefilr.js");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to stare callbacks? If so you don't need to use anonymous functions, try this:

```
function myCallback(chart) {
   // code
}

var options = { 
    chart: {
        ..
    }, 

    // more options

    series: [{ 
        data: [ .. ]
    }]
}

$("#container").highcharts( options, callback );
```